# How instagram and similar sites, manages to show Profile picture for every comments in a post?

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose

I am using **nodejs and mongodb (mongoose)** to create a **social media like site** where users can comment on a post. I want to show the profile picture and the username of the user who has made a particular comment. Comments for posts are stored in a collection and the schema is as follows:

```
{
    commentMessage: String,
    senderUserName: String, 
    senderPictureLink: String, 
    timestamp: Number, 
}
```

But I realized that this approach leads to lot of **duplication of profile picture link**. 
Querying the **useraccounts collection for the profile picture link** of the users who commented on the post will lead to lot of find() queries. 
So I need to know how the big social networking sites are doing this.

Comment: You might want to take a look at Socialite. This is an example application that provides API-only (no front end) that implements a social networking site: https://github.com/mongodb-labs/socialite